# punjab installed and runs, but can not connect to http://mydomain:5280/xmpp-httpbind

Tags: xmpp, strophe, punjab

I have Punjab installed on Ubuntu, which has apache and is a web
server. However,  when I launch the page http://mydomain:5280/xmpp-httpbind,
I got the following error msg :

```
" Network Error (tcp_error)
 communication error occurred: "Operation timed out
  The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time."
```

The twisted.log does not say very much:

```
 2011-08-12 10:02:33+0200 [-] Log opened.
 2011-08-12 10:02:33+0200 [-] twistd 10.2.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.1) starting up.
 2011-08-12 10:02:33+0200 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
 2011-08-12 10:02:33+0200 [-] twisted.web.server.Site starting on 5280
 2011-08-12 10:02:33+0200 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x19c0ef0>
```

The important settings in the punjab.tac file is:

```
root.putChild('http-bind', resource.IResource(bosh))
site  = server.Site(root)
application = service.Application("punjab")
internet.TCPServer(5280, site).setServiceParent(application)
```

I am sitting behind a company proxy. Is this the reason? Thanks for
your kind help!

/Stella

Answer (score 0):

did you try connecting to http://mydomain:5280/http-bind?